# javascript - animate numbers with json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a problem with animated number effect when grabbing data from json.

Animated number effect works correctly if it loads from html, but if I load it from json it doesn't work.

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.animateNumbers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

<body>
  Time from html (<span class="animate-number" data-value="2" data-animation-duration="600"></span>:<span class="animate-number" data-value="33" data-animation-duration="600"></span>h)

<div id="display_time"></div>

<script>
  $('.animate-number').each(function(){
     $(this).animateNumbers($(this).attr("data-value"), true, parseInt($(this).attr("data-animation-duration")));
  })
</script>

 <script>
   $(function time(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data_time.php",
        data: "get_time=true",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
           $("#display_time").html(data.time);
        }
     });
   });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

data_time.php code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['get_time']))
   {
     $time[] =  'Time from json (<span class="animate-number" data-value="2" data-animation-duration="600"></span>:<span class="animate-number" data-value="33" data-animation-duration="600"></span>h)';
     echo json_encode(array('time' => $time ));
   }

;?>
```

preview: [click](http://obisci.me/time.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with callback. Try this,

```
<script>
function runCallback(){
  $('.animate-number').each(function(){
     $(this).animateNumbers($(this).attr("data-value"), true, parseInt($(this).attr("data-animation-duration")));
  })
}
</script>

 <script>
   $(function time(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data_time.php",
        data: "get_time=true",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
           $("#display_time").html(data.time);
           runCallback();
        }
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$time` instead of `$time[]`.  There's no need for it to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Take out dataType:'json'.  You are not SENDING json.

Comment: ["dataType: The type of data that you're expecting **back** from the server."](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)